# How do you use Rice's theorem and why does it make sense? (Use provided Rice's theorem)

Tags: rice-theorem

So this is the Rice's theorem we were provided:

Definition: $TM$-$FUNC(S)$

Input: Turing machine $M$

Question: Is $f_M \in S$

Let $S$ be a set of computable partial functions with $\emptyset \neq S \neq R$, where $R$ is the set of all functions computable by a Turing machine. Then $TM$-$FUNC(S)$ is undecidable.

In other words, for any set $S$, that is, for any non-trivial semantic property of a function, we cannot check algorithmically whether $f_M\in S$

Online, I only found videos using Rice's theorem by coming up with two random Turing machines, where one is part of the language of the problem and the other is not. (With language of the problem I'm referring to all inputs where the question of the problem is answered why "yes"). They referred to this part as 'non-trivial'

Additionally, they then claimed that for any random Turing machines, not the random ones picked before but any, it is not possible to say $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$ if one is inside the language of the problem and the other is not.

I understand how this 'non-trivial' thing may seem useful, as it is related to the actual problem but the second part is beyond me, because you're not using the ones you found but make a claim for arbitrary ones out of nowhere.

If both these claims/properties/whatever hold, then Rice's theorem may be applied and we can declare the problem to be undecidable.

Here the source of that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kr7n_3LpWhc

My question: **How does this version of Rice's theorem relate to what I was provided with and why does this make sense?** Because only the non-trivial property has a direct connection to the problem we want to declare undecidable by Rice's theorem, the other one seems unrelated.